# Delphi MySQL Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

I've decieded I play with mySQL a bit . Installed the latest version (8.x) and I downloaded from the Internet (6.1.11) . I am using 32 bit right now .

Anyways I am connected to the Database , all is working fine . I have one FireDac Connection on the MainForm . If I open a query it works , I can even open close the query no problem .

But if I try to execute a stored procedure , it inserts what I wanted , but after that . I receive the error : **Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**

Here is how I open a Query :

```
  if UserQuery.Active then UserQuery.Close;
  case PageControl1.ActivePageIndex of
    0: UserQuery.Params.ParamByName('Active').Value:=1;
    1: UserQuery.Params.ParamByName('Active').Value:=0;
  end;
  UserQuery.Open();
```

This works multiple times, if I change the tabs it either Opens with Active 1 or 0 , and I never get the Out of Sync Error.

Then I try to insert a new user like this :

```
  if Modify = false then
    begin
      UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pOP').Value:='INS';
    end
  else
    begin

    end;

  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pName').Value:=Edit1.Text;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pPassword').Value:=Edit2.Text;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pRights').Value:=ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pModifierID').Value:=Main.UserID;
  UserMain.spUser.ExecProc;
```

It is inserted imediatelly , but after this , I can no longer do anything, If I try to Open the Query the error comes. Even if I close this Form completely it still comes as long as I do not close the Application and Restart it.

Obviously I am doing something wrong , but what ?

The Stored Procedure returns two values, maybe I am not handling this correctly . I used before this MsSQL ... and ADOStoredProcedure , I never had this problem before .

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spuser`(
 IN pOP varchar(10),
 IN pID int,
 IN pName varchar(50),
 IN pPassword varchar(140),
 IN pRights int,
 IN pModifierID int,
 IN pLocked int,
 IN pLockedUserID int,
 IN pLockedDate datetime,
 OUT pBackID int,
 OUT pERROR int
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE plock int;
  DECLARE pActive int;
  DECLARE CheckInsert int;  
  DECLARE CheckModify int;
  SET CheckInsert = 0;
  SET CheckModify = 0;

  set plock = (select ifnull(Locked,0) from tbl_user where ID=pID);
  set pActive = (select ifnull(Active,0) from tbl_user where ID=pID);  

  IF pOP='LOCK' THEN
      IF plock=0 THEN
          UPDATE tbl_user set Locked=1,LockedUserID=pLockedUserID,LockedDate=current_timestamp()
          where ID=pID;
        END IF;
      IF plock=1 THEN
          UPDATE tbl_user set Locked=0,LockedUserID='0',LockedDate=null
          where ID=pID;
        END IF;
  END IF;

  IF pOP='LOCKTIME' THEN
    UPDATE tbl_user set LockedDate=current_timestamp() where ID=pID;
  END IF;

  IF pOP='INS' THEN 
      SELECT count(*) INTO CheckInsert from tbl_user where Name=pName;
      IF (CheckInsert = 0) THEN
            INSERT INTO tbl_user(Name,Password,Rights,ModifierID,ModifyDate,Locked,LockedUserID,LockedDate,Active)
            VALUES(pName,pPassword,pRights,pModifierID,current_timestamp(),-1,-1,null,1);
            SET pERROR = '0';
            SET pBackID = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
       ELSE
           SET pERROR='1'; 
       END IF;
  END IF;

  IF pOP='UPD' THEN 
       SELECT count(*) INTO CheckModify from tbl_user where Name=pName and id<>pID;
       IF (CheckModify = 0) THEN
            UPDATE tbl_user SET Name=pName,
                    Password=pPassword,
                    Rights=pRights,
                    ModifierID=pModifierID,
                    ModifyDate=current_timestamp(),
                    Locked=-1,
                    LockedUserID=-1,
                    LockedDate=null,
                    Active=1
            where ID=pID;
            SET pERROR='0';
       ELSE
           SET pERROR='1'; 
       END IF;
   END IF;

  IF pOP='ACT' THEN
      IF pActive=1 THEN
          UPDATE tbl_user set Active=0
          where ID=pID;
        END IF;
      IF pActive=0 THEN
          UPDATE tbl_user set Active=1
          where ID=pID;
        END IF;
  END IF;

END
```

Please Help.

Thank you

**UPDATE 1**

I kinda fixed it like this :

```
procedure spconnection( connection : TFDConnection );
var AStream : TStringStream;
begin
  if connection.Connected then connection.Close;

  connection.Params.Clear;
  connection.Params.Add('DriverID=MySQL');

  AStream := inireadstream('\Data\mysql.conf','SERVER','Password');

  connection.Params.Add('Password='+aes_decrypt(AStream));
  connection.Params.Add('Server'+iniread('\Data\mysql.conf','SERVER','Server'));
  connection.Params.Add('Port='+iniread('\Data\mysql.conf','SERVER','Port'));
  connection.Params.Add('User_Name='+iniread('\Data\mysql.conf','SERVER','UserName'));
  connection.Params.Add('Database=x');
  connection.Params.Add('CharacterSet=utf8mb4');


  try
    connection.Connected:=true;
  except
    on E : EFDDBEngineException do
      begin
        MessageDlg(E.Message,mtERROR,[mbOK],0);
        Application.Terminate;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

I've set my Stored Procedure to use MySQLsp Connection . And before I execute the Stored Procedure I do this .

```
  spconnection(Main.MySQLsp);

  if Modify = false then
    begin
      UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pOP').Value:='INS';
    end
  else
    begin

    end;

  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pName').Value:=Edit1.Text;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pPassword').Value:=Edit2.Text;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pRights').Value:=ComboBox1.ItemIndex;
  UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamByName('pModifierID').Value:=Main.UserID;
  UserMain.spUser.ExecProc;

  if UserMain.spUser.Params.ParamValues['pERROR'] = 1 then
    begin
      MessageDlg('BENUTZERNAME BEREITS VORHANDEN',mtError,[mbOK],0);
    end
  else
    begin
      UserMain.PageControl1.OnChange(self);
      ModalResult:=1;
    end;
```

This works, but I feel this is a bubblegum solution :) . Anyone know of a better way .

Comment: I don't know if this is a behavior by design , but it seems like if I use a dedicated Connection for the Stored Procedures , which I reconnect each time it works .

Comment: it also works if I use one FDConnection , which I reconnect every time before I do something ... this way forcing it to commit . But I am still not sure which property I have set false.

Comment: i have the same error when i use just a SELECT inside stored procedure, i think u must see in this context (I use ZEOS to connect to my databases).

Comment: but a Fix you have not? I just opened MySQL Dashboard and execute my Stored Procedure a few times like this :
call x.spUser('INS',null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,@out,@out2);
There is no error . So this must be something I incorrectly configured on the FDConnection or the FDStoredProcedure. But I have no idea what .

Comment: the only rule in my case is to not use select without variable in stored proc called from an application (An Select how return result in screen), with ZEOS i use this parameters in connector (TZConnection->Properties) "CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS=1", I dont know what use with FDConnection